# how to use VB.NET 2015 or 2017 on an Azure Windows Server 2012 VM to programmatically send a message to the 10-digit mobile number of an SMS device

Tags: c#, iphone, vb.net, sms, sms-gateway

Given the 10-digit mobile# of, say, an iPhone, how can .NET send a message (<= 160 chars) to arrive as a text message at the device (iPhone or Android)?

If I knew the mobile# ranges of each carrier's domain, then I could email via SMTP to: 
<10-digit#>@
But I haven't found any table of carrier domains vs. mobile#.

Answer (score 0):

direct sms from c# isn't something you'll be able to code, you'll need to have connections to the telcom networks, which is not something you'll be able to get without some hardcore company resources and negotiations behind you. unless you use a 3rd party api, tropo is one that i use, there's a few more out there that provide the similar api's